# How to work with arrays within arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have an `int[][] anArray = new int[4][4];`

And let's say that I wanted to make row 3 of anArray {1, 2, 3, 4}. Could I do that without manually assigning each individual value its value? What if it was column 2 of anArray?

I'm posting this because it's rather inconvenient to do stuff like this:

```
int[][] foo = new int[bar][baz];
//
//Code that uses other columns of foo
//
for (int n=0; n < bar; n++)
    foo[n][1] = bin[n];
```

Comment: A suggestion: `foo[2] = new int[]{1,2,3,4};`.

Comment: I'll make a suggestion since I won't be answering your question, really.  The answer is, "Don't".  Instead, use collection classes such as ArrayList or HashMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here is the code to assign row index 3 of `anArray` as `{1,2,3,4}` without loops:

```
int[][] anArray = new int[4][4];
anArray[3] = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(anArray));
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: @Keyser you're welcome. There's always some possibility of semantic confusion about indexing since it starts at 0, so of course as you imply "row 3" might be `anArray[2]` - I just chose `anArray[3]` for reasons beyond my own understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the entire row of a two-dimensional array to another (one-dimensional) array, you can simply do

```
int[][] foo = new int [3][3];
int[] bin={1,2,3};
foo[1] = bin;
```

If want to assign the column though, I am afraid that you can only do it manually...

Answer (score 0):

```
anArray[3] = new int [] {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is basically an *array of arrays* and so we can add full arrays in one go:

```
int[][] array = new int[4][4];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper method to set a column:

```
public class MatrixTest {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Integer[][] target = new Integer[3][2];
    setMatrixColumn( target, 1, new Integer[]{ 1, 1, 1 } );

    System.out.println( Arrays.deepToString( target ) );
  }

  public static <T> void setMatrixColumn(T[][] matrix, int index, T[] values) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++ )
      matrix[i][index] = values[index];
  }
}
```